# Customized Bootstrap into Less format

Tags: github, twitter-bootstrap, less, html5boilerplate

Is there anyway to download a customised version of twitter boostrap (where you can edit the colours, grid widths etc) that gives you the css in .less format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bootstrap is in Less: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/master/less (as of 3.0.0)

There is a SASS version here: https://github.com/jlong/sass-twitter-bootstrap

Edit: You can "fork" one of those versions, & add your own edits to it.  You can use GitHub for free if you do not mind if your fork is available to others publicly.

Comment: The first link is now dead. (Probably since Bootstrap 3 was launched.)

Comment: ty @beporter; actually they changed repositories.

Answer (score 2):

The bootstrap package comes with the less sheets already included so you can [download](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/bootstrap.zip) the whole package from GitHub and start working right away. You can also modify most of the styles on the bootstrap by customizing your download over at the [Customize](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html) section on the Bootstrap documentation page that will also render the changes you make in less.

[Here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/extend.html) is the bootstrap less documentation.